# Duplicate entry error - JSONPath with GSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, jsonpath

I am using JSONPATH library with GSON

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.1.0'
```

i have used these two libraries. When i build my project, it does not show any error. But when i run my project, it shows

> Error:Execution failed for task '**:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class**" error.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.2'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.0.0'

}
```

This is my build.gradle.

The problem is in libraries. It shows duplicate entry of a file.

Comment: You will need to show some code.

Comment: @Shawn i have posted the build.gradle file

Comment: compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1'

This version of jsonPath library solved the issue. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the conflicting library, e.g.:

```
compile ('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0') { exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm' }
```